# MySQL foreign key failure with varchar variables

Tags: mysql

I have issues with a pair of parent-child tables in MySQL 5.6.10. Django app is also involved downstream, as well as .tab data files originating from SAS.

The parent table (ccs1) defines 18 high-level medical codes that I'm labeling idx, and which uses a varchar(2) field for numbers 1 to 18. The child defines 138 sub-codes, which provide another level of medical detail for the parent-level codes: 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, etc., also labeled idx within it's own table. Within the child I create an additional `varchar(2)` variable named ccs1_id that is the first number in the child's idx code, and am attempting to set it as a foreign key reference to the equivalent idx variable in the parent table. (This is using industry standard CCS tables for those who are curious - and there are 4 levels in total, such as 4.4.5.1, otherwise I wouldn't be keeping with the varchar representation).

Data insertion with foreign_key_checks = 0 fails upon reading in the child table. When I turn off key checks the data appears to read in properly (when viewed within the MySQL workbench gui). When I attempt to use the data in a django application and filter child table values via the parent foreign key reference it only successfully filters for the high-level codes that are *2* digit (character): 10. 18. Filtering off of parent-level keys 1 to 9 fails.

Both tables are constructed with the related variables as varchar(2) - I've included the SHOW CREATE TABLE output for each further below.

My best clue so far is from the latest foreign key error off of the SHOW ENGINE logs for when I try to load parent child tables, foreign_key_checks = 1. Parent loads successfully, then child fails with:

```
TRANSACTION 1022234, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 5000
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 320, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 177, OS thread handle 0x2280, query id 12426 localhost 127.0.0.1 root        
System lock
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/abc/dim_dx_ccs2.tab'
INTO TABLE dim_dx_ccs2
IGNORE 1 LINES
(idx, idxm, label, ccs1_id)
Foreign key constraint fails for table `phrat`.`dim_dx_ccs2`:
,
CONSTRAINT `ccs1_id_refs_idx_1213764e` FOREIGN KEY (`ccs1_id`) REFERENCES `dim_dx_ccs1`    (`idx`)
Trying to add in child table, in index `ccs1_id_refs_idx_1213764e` tuple:
DATA TUPLE: 2 fields;
0: len 2; hex 310d; asc 1 ;;
1: len 4; hex 80000103; asc     ;;

But in parent table `phrat`.`dim_dx_ccs1`, in index `idx`,
the closest match we can find is record:
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 1; hex 31; asc 1;;
1: len 4; hex 80000052; asc    R;;
```

In this case it should be searching for a value of "1" in the parent table. Looking at last 9 lines, it looks like MySQL's varchar data type is treating the parent table's idx value as having a length of 1 after trimming and comparing it to a value with a length of 2 prior to trimming? That said, the given hex values of 310d(decimal:12557) and 31(decimal:49) don't make any sense given the data I'm reading in, which should only be between 1 and 18. The hex values for the 1: fields look appropriate, those would be the primary keys (ID) for each table, the very first entry (which would be "1" or "1 " for the foreign key value).

Am I missing something more fundamental here, or is this the root of the problem? And if so how might I resolve it? I suppose I could switch to set-length CHAR values and that might resolve, but I want to make sure I understand what's going on here.

For reference here is the SHOW CREATE TABLE output

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 dim_dx_ccs1 | CREATE TABLE `dim_dx_ccs1` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `idx` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `idxm` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `label` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `idx` (`idx`),
 UNIQUE KEY `idxm` (`idxm`)
 ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=65 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


 dim_dx_ccs2 | CREATE TABLE `dim_dx_ccs2` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `idx` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `idxm` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `label` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `ccs1_id` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `idx` (`idx`),
 UNIQUE KEY `idxm` (`idxm`),
 KEY `ccs1_id_refs_idx_1213764e` (`ccs1_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `ccs1_id_refs_idx_1213764e` FOREIGN KEY (`ccs1_id`) REFERENCES `dim_dx_ccs1` (`idx`)
 ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=259 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Additional details:

- The data tables originate from a Unix server (where SAS resides) but are then exported as .tab files to a Windows environment.

Comment: Exporting on Windows, importing on Unix/Linux?

Comment: Good point - adding answer to this and any future Qs to body of question, "Additional Details" at bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the details, it looks like the `tab` file has CR/LF in it while the import expects LF only.

That makes the expected 0x31 ('1') import as 0x31 0x0d ('1\r'), which does not match any value in your primary table and thus the import fails.

Comment: Ahh!  Shame on me for misreading the hex number there.  That's exactly it - I added  " SET ccs1_id = TRIM(TRAILING '\r' FROM ccs1_id);  " onto the infile statement and everything works like a charm now.  Thank you!!